# Visual Studio Database project with CLR reference issue

Tags: c#, database, visual-studio

I have an existing Database project that I'd like to add CLR functions to. I have it working fine on the actual DB and can script it out to the project (also fine) but I want to keep the CLR C# source consistent with the DB project.

I'm looking for a solution where when I build/deploy it will first build the CLR C# project, then replace the DB project's referenced assembly and deploy all of it together. Is this possible? If so can someone please explain the steps required to do this?